# XSLT targeting an element depending on a CustomTagAttribs type

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML doc that shows this:

```
<Element>
  <Content>

    <CustomTagAttribs>
      <type>breadcrumb</type>
    </CustomTagAttribs>

    <ElementData>
      <LBarItem>TEXT!</LBarItem>
    </ElementData>

  </Content>
<Element>
```

And there is another `<Element>` instance just like the one above, but without the `<type>breadcrumb</type>`. I want to target the LBarItems only in the `<Element>` that has the breadcrumb type. How would I do this?

This is what I have been trying:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Content/ElementData/LBarItem">
  <xsl:if test="../type='breadcrumb'">
    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that shows how to avoid completely using conditional logic when solving such problems. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
/Element/Content[CustomTagAttribs/type = 'breadcrumb']/ElementData/LBarItem
```

Comment: So then, is there a way to specify LBarItems that are NOT within the "breadcrumb" element? The other element I have does not have a type specified so I can't target it. I tried adding "!" to CustomTagAttribs/type!='breadcrumb' but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @jrottier: You wrote *I tried adding "!" [...] but that didn't seem to work*. That's because node set comparison is **existencial comparison**. So, if there are many `type` children (even one being equal to 'breadcrumb'), then at least one without 'breadcrumb' string value would make the comparison true. But if there is no `type` element, then the `!=` comparison should result false because there would be no one different than 'breadcrumb'.

Comment: I see. So is there a way to specify show all `/Element/Content/ElementData/LBarItem` items but not if it has a `type=breadcrumb`?

Comment: @jrottier: Yes `/Element/Content[not(CustomTagAttribs/type = 'breadcrumb')]/ElementData/LBarItem` if there is more than one **or none** `CustomTagAttribs/type`. If you positibly know there is one and only one `CustomTagAttribs/type` per `/Element/Content`, then you could simple use `/Element/Content[CustomTagAttribs/type != 'breadcrumb']/ElementData/LBarItem`

Comment: @jrottier: You are wellcome, ask any time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `<xsl:for-each>` and any conditional logic at all.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Content[CustomTagAttribs/type='breadcrumb']/*/LBarItem">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (containing two `Element` elements):

```
<t>
    <Element>
        <Content>
            <CustomTagAttribs>
                <type>breadcrumb</type>
            </CustomTagAttribs>
            <ElementData>
                <LBarItem>I have "breadcrumb" type</LBarItem>
            </ElementData>
        </Content>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Content>
            <CustomTagAttribs>
                <type>something else</type>
            </CustomTagAttribs>
            <ElementData>
                <LBarItem>I have "something else" type</LBarItem>
            </ElementData>
        </Content>
    </Element>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<LBarItem>I have "breadcrumb" type</LBarItem>
```